# После 30-50 часов работы приложение закрывается. В логе: Abort message: 'ubsan: add-overflow'. Что делать?

Tags: java, android

Приложение работает, все хорошо. Но после 30-50 часов выходит без каких либо уведомлений. В логе виже ошибку: Abort message: 'ubsan: add-overflow'

Вот logcat стек:

```
    05-25 23:17:03.993 25553 25571 I homesystems.rv: Background concurrent copying GC freed 25535(1694KB) AllocSpace objects, 11(204KB) LOS objects, 49% free, 1877KB/3755KB, paused 582us total 189.881ms
05-25 23:17:06.262 25553 25553 F libc    : Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -1 (SI_QUEUE) in tid 25553 (homesystems.rvp), pid 25553 (homesystems.rvp)
05-25 23:17:06.351 25593 25593 E cutils-trace: Error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
05-25 23:17:06.431 25594 25594 I crash_dump32: obtaining output fd from tombstoned, type: kDebuggerdTombstone
05-25 23:17:06.443  1885  1885 I /system/bin/tombstoned: received crash request for pid 25553
05-25 23:17:06.450 25594 25594 I crash_dump32: performing dump of process 25553 (target tid = 25553)
05-25 23:17:06.482 25594 25594 F DEBUG   : *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
05-25 23:17:06.482 25594 25594 F DEBUG   : Build fingerprint: 'google/walley/walleye:10/QP1A.191105.004/eng.linux.20200228.134026:userdebug/test-keys'
05-25 23:17:06.482 25594 25594 F DEBUG   : Revision: '0'
05-25 23:17:06.483 25594 25594 F DEBUG   : ABI: 'arm'
05-25 23:17:06.494 25594 25594 F DEBUG   : Timestamp: 2021-05-25 23:17:06+0300
05-25 23:17:06.494 25594 25594 F DEBUG   : pid: 25553, tid: 25553, name: homesystems.rvp  >>> com.intellhomesystems.rvp <<<
05-25 23:17:06.495 25594 25594 F DEBUG   : uid: 10090
05-25 23:17:06.804 25594 25594 I crash_dump32: type=1400 audit(0.0:15411): avc: denied { read } for name="libjvmtiagent_arm.so" dev="mmcblk0p17" ino=79834 scontext=u:r:crash_dump:s0:c90,c256,c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:app_data_file:s0 tclass=file permissive=1 app=com.intellhomesystems.rvp
05-25 23:17:06.495 25594 25594 F DEBUG   : signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -1 (SI_QUEUE), fault addr --------
05-25 23:17:06.804 25594 25594 I crash_dump32: type=1400 audit(0.0:15412): avc: denied { open } for path="/data/data/com.intellhomesystems.rvp/code_cache/libjvmtiagent_arm.so" dev="mmcblk0p17" ino=79834 scontext=u:r:crash_dump:s0:c90,c256,c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:app_data_file:s0 tclass=file permissive=1 app=com.intellhomesystems.rvp
05-25 23:17:06.496 25594 25594 F DEBUG   : Abort message: 'ubsan: add-overflow'
05-25 23:17:06.496 25594 25594 F DEBUG   :     r0  00000000  r1  000063d1  r2  00000006  r3  ff859430
05-25 23:17:06.496 25594 25594 F DEBUG   :     r4  ff859444  r5  ff859428  r6  000063d1  r7  0000016b
05-25 23:17:06.496 25594 25594 F DEBUG   :     r8  ff859440  r9  ff859430  r10 ff859460  r11 ff859450
05-25 23:17:06.496 25594 25594 F DEBUG   :     ip  000063d1  sp  ff859400  lr  e75bccb7  pc  e75bccca
05-25 23:17:07.769 25594 25594 F DEBUG   : 
05-25 23:17:07.769 25594 25594 F DEBUG   : backtrace:
05-25 23:17:07.769 25594 25594 F DEBUG   :       #00 pc 0005ecca  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/bionic/libc.so (abort+166) (BuildId: 382e04da0c4d6d7d06edbd53601a5dd4)
05-25 23:17:07.769 25594 25594 F DEBUG   :       #01 pc 0001c1d8  /system/lib/libminikin.so (abort_with_message(char const*)+24) (BuildId: f71e712befe99bff4f7952e8bbdb3771)
05-25 23:17:07.769 25594 25594 F DEBUG   :       #02 pc 0001c1f8  /system/lib/libminikin.so (__ubsan_handle_add_overflow_minimal_abort+24) (BuildId: f71e712befe99bff4f7952e8bbdb3771)
05-25 23:17:07.770 25594 25594 F DEBUG   :       #03 pc 00010d81  /system/lib/libminikin.so (void minikin::LayoutCache::getOrCreate<minikin::LayoutAppendFunctor>(minikin::U16StringPiece const&, minikin::Range const&, minikin::MinikinPaint const&, bool, minikin::StartHyphenEdit, minikin::EndHyphenEdit, minikin::LayoutAppendFunctor&)+396) (BuildId: f71e712befe99bff4f7952e8bbdb3771)
05-25 23:17:07.770 25594 25594 F DEBUG   :       #04 pc 00010b13  /system/lib/libminikin.so (minikin::Layout::doLayoutWord(unsigned short const*, unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned int, bool, minikin::MinikinPaint const&, unsigned int, minikin::StartHyphenEdit, minikin::EndHyphenEdit, minikin::Layout*, float*)+146) (BuildId: f71e712befe99bff4f7952e8bbdb3771)
05-25 23:17:07.771 25594 25594 F DEBUG   :       #05 pc 00010971  /system/lib/libminikin.so (minikin::Layout::doLayoutRunCached(minikin::U16StringPiece const&, minikin::Range const&, bool, minikin::MinikinPaint const&, unsigned int, minikin::StartHyphenEdit, minikin::EndHyphenEdit, minikin::Layout*, float*)+312) (BuildId: f71e712befe99bff4f7952e8bbdb3771)
05-25 23:17:07.771 25594 25594 F DEBUG   :       #06 pc 00010759  /system/lib/libminikin.so (minikin::Layout::doLayout(minikin::U16StringPiece const&, minikin::Range const&, minikin::Bidi, minikin::MinikinPaint const&, minikin::StartHyphenEdit, minikin::EndHyphenEdit)+156) (BuildId: f71e712befe99bff4f7952e8bbdb3771)
05-25 23:17:07.771 25594 25594 F DEBUG   :       #07 pc 0020cedf  /system/lib/libhwui.so (android::MinikinUtils::doLayout(android::Paint const*, minikin::Bidi, android::Typeface const*, unsigned short const*, unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned int, minikin::MeasuredText*)+138) (BuildId: 2b5c31ac5950d23507027b4683e3536a)
05-25 23:17:07.772 25594 25594 F DEBUG   :       #08 pc 0020caf7  /system/lib/libhwui.so (android::Canvas::drawText(unsigned short const*, int, int, int, int, int, float, float, minikin::Bidi, android::Paint const&, android::Typeface const*, minikin::MeasuredText*)+82) (BuildId: 2b5c31ac5950d23507027b4683e3536a)
05-25 23:17:07.772 25594 25594 F DEBUG   :       #09 pc 000ac9d7  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (android::CanvasJNI::drawTextString(_JNIEnv*, _jobject*, long long, _jstring*, int, int, float, float, int, long long)+138) (BuildId: 14c98437e171a2edb14595cf0e1310f9)
05-25 23:17:07.772 25594 25594 F DEBUG   :       #10 pc 0029642b  /system/framework/arm/boot-framework.oat (art_jni_trampoline+194) (BuildId: 57e39866938bab563b7c587c27534e03b4a54b2f)
05-25 23:17:07.772 25594 25594 F DEBUG   :       #11 pc 02026139  /memfd:/jit-cache (deleted) (android.graphics.BaseRecordingCanvas.drawText+120)
05-25 23:17:07.773 25594 25594 F DEBUG   :       #12 pc 02038077  /memfd:/jit-cache (deleted) (android.text.BoringLayout.draw+118)
05-25 23:17:07.776 25594 25594 F DEBUG   :       #13 pc 02027bfb  /memfd:/jit-cache (deleted) (android.widget.TextView.onDraw+3002)
05-25 23:17:07.777 25594 25594 F DEBUG   :       #14 pc 020206cb  /memfd:/jit-cache (deleted) (android.view.View.draw+1930)
05-25 23:17:07.777 25594 25594 F DEBUG   :       #15 pc 0201d601  /memfd:/jit-cache (deleted) (android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty+704)
05-25 23:17:07.777 25594 25594 F DEBUG   :       #16 pc 0201c2af  /memfd:/jit-cache (deleted) (android.view.View.draw+1006)
05-25 23:17:07.777 25594 25594 F DEBUG   :       #17 pc 0201e1f7  /memfd:/jit-cache (deleted) (android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild+54)
05-25 23:17:07.777 25594 25594 F DEBUG   :       #18 pc 0201fb71  /memfd:/jit-cache (deleted) (android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw+1328)
05-25 23:17:07.777 25594 25594 F DEBUG   :       #19 pc 02021a51  /memfd:/jit-cache (deleted) (androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.dispatchDraw+208)
05-25 23:17:07.777 25594 25594 F DEBUG   :       #20 pc 0201ffef  /memfd:/jit-cache (deleted) (android.view.View.draw+174)
05-25 23:17:07.777 25594 25594 F DEBUG   :       #21 pc 0201d601  /memfd:/jit-cache (deleted) (android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty+704)
05-25 23:17:07.777 25594 25594 F DEBUG   :       #22 pc 020048c7  /memfd:/jit-cache (deleted) (java.util.Arrays.copyOf+70)
05-25 23:17:07.777 25594 25594 F DEBUG   :       #23 pc 020026d9  /memfd:/jit-cache (deleted) (sun.security.x509.AVA.toRFC2253CanonicalString+152)
05-25 23:17:07.778 25594 25594 F DEBUG   :       #24 pc 0201d42d  /memfd:/jit-cache (deleted) (android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty+236)
05-25 23:17:07.778 25594 25594 F DEBUG   :       #25 pc 020048c7  /memfd:/jit-cache (deleted) (java.util.Arrays.copyOf+70)
05-25 23:17:07.778 25594 25594 F DEBUG   :       #26 pc 020026d9  /memfd:/jit-cache (deleted) (sun.security.x509.AVA.toRFC2253CanonicalString+152)
05-25 23:17:07.778 25594 25594 F DEBUG   :       #27 pc 0201d42d  /memfd:/jit-cache (deleted) (android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty+236)
05-25 23:17:07.778 25594 25594 F DEBUG   :       #28 pc 020048c7  /memfd:/jit-cache (deleted) (java.util.Arrays.copyOf+70)
05-25 23:17:07.779 25594 25594 F DEBUG   :       #29 pc 020026d9  /memfd:/jit-cache (deleted) (sun.security.x509.AVA.toRFC2253CanonicalString+152)
05-25 23:17:07.780 25594 25594 F DEBUG   :       #30 pc 0201d42d  /memfd:/jit-cache (deleted) (android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty+236)
05-25 23:17:07.781 25594 25594 F DEBUG   :       #31 pc 02028597  /memfd:/jit-cache (deleted) (android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateViewTreeDisplayList+86)
05-25 23:17:07.782 25594 25594 F DEBUG   :       #32 pc 02023d53  /memfd:/jit-cache (deleted) (android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateRootDisplayList+82)
05-25 23:17:07.782 25594 25594 F DEBUG   :       #33 pc 020360b1  /memfd:/jit-cache (deleted) (android.view.ThreadedRenderer.draw+112)
05-25 23:17:07.782 25594 25594 F DEBUG   :       #34 pc 02035a61  /memfd:/jit-cache (deleted) (android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw+1696)
05-25 23:17:07.782 25594 25594 F DEBUG   :       #35 pc 020291a9  /memfd:/jit-cache (deleted) (android.view.ViewRootImpl.performDraw+616)
05-25 23:17:07.782 25594 25594 F DEBUG   :       #36 pc 020331b7  /memfd:/jit-cache (deleted) (android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals+11766)
05-25 23:17:07.782 25594 25594 F DEBUG   :       #37 pc 0203c25d  /memfd:/jit-cache (deleted) (android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal+156)
05-25 23:17:07.782 25594 25594 F DEBUG   :       #38 pc 02039835  /memfd:/jit-cache (deleted) (android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run+52)
05-25 23:17:07.782 25594 25594 F DEBUG   :       #39 pc 02001007  /memfd:/jit-cache (deleted) (android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run+198)
05-25 23:17:07.783 25594 25594 F DEBUG   :       #40 pc 0201f2e5  /memfd:/jit-cache (deleted) (android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks+548)
05-25 23:17:07.783 25594 25594 F DEBUG   :       #41 pc 02005751  /memfd:/jit-cache (deleted) (com.android.okhttp.okio.Buffer.writeUtf8+976)
05-25 23:17:07.783 25594 25594 F DEBUG   :       #42 pc 0203b6c9  /memfd:/jit-cache (deleted) (android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run+72)
05-25 23:17:07.783 25594 25594 F DEBUG   :       #43 pc 0200cef9  /memfd:/jit-cache (deleted) (android.database.CursorWindow.getString+56)
05-25 23:17:07.783 25594 25594 F DEBUG   :       #44 pc 0200b5ff  /memfd:/jit-cache (deleted) (com.android.internal.util.LineBreakBufferedWriter.write+318)
05-25 23:17:07.783 25594 25594 F DEBUG   :       #45 pc 0202fadb  /memfd:/jit-cache (deleted) (android.os.Looper.loop+1114)
05-25 23:17:07.783 25594 25594 F DEBUG   :       #46 pc 000d7c0f  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (art_quick_osr_stub+46) (BuildId: a8203f4dd0e190bd1cbb4e57d1af3c8d)
05-25 23:17:07.783 25594 25594 F DEBUG   :       #47 pc 0025c31f  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (art::jit::Jit::MaybeDoOnStackReplacement(art::Thread*, art::ArtMethod*, unsigned int, int, art::JValue*)+1134) (BuildId: a8203f4dd0e190bd1cbb4e57d1af3c8d)
05-25 23:17:07.783 25594 25594 F DEBUG   :       #48 pc 0021ac13  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (void art::interpreter::ExecuteSwitchImplCpp<false, false>(art::interpreter::SwitchImplContext*)+8354) (BuildId: a8203f4dd0e190bd1cbb4e57d1af3c8d)
05-25 23:17:07.784 25594 25594 F DEBUG   :       #49 pc 000dd075  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (ExecuteSwitchImplAsm+4) (BuildId: a8203f4dd0e190bd1cbb4e57d1af3c8d)
05-25 23:17:07.784 25594 25594 F DEBUG   :       #50 pc 0031bd58  /system/framework/framework.jar (android.os.Looper.loop)
05-25 23:17:07.785 25594 25594 F DEBUG   :       #51 pc 0043876d  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (MterpInvokeStatic+1080) (BuildId: a8203f4dd0e190bd1cbb4e57d1af3c8d)
05-25 23:17:07.785 25594 25594 F DEBUG   :       #52 pc 000d2994  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (mterp_op_invoke_static+20) (BuildId: a8203f4dd0e190bd1cbb4e57d1af3c8d)
05-25 23:17:07.785 25594 25594 F DEBUG   :       #53 pc 00189dde  /system/framework/framework.jar (android.app.ActivityThread.main+194)
05-25 23:17:07.786 25594 25594 F DEBUG   :       #54 pc 001f0d0b  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreterL7ExecuteEPNS_6ThreadERKNS_20CodeItemDataAccessorERNS_11ShadowFrameENS_6JValueEbb.llvm.17460432879466217+170) (BuildId: a8203f4dd0e190bd1cbb4e57d1af3c8d)
05-25 23:17:07.786 25594 25594 F DEBUG   :       #55 pc 001f56ed  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (art::interpreter::EnterInterpreterFromEntryPoint(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame*)+120) (BuildId: a8203f4dd0e190bd1cbb4e57d1af3c8d)
05-25 23:17:07.786 25594 25594 F DEBUG   :       #56 pc 0042a589  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (artQuickToInterpreterBridge+820) (BuildId: a8203f4dd0e190bd1cbb4e57d1af3c8d)
05-25 23:17:07.786 25594 25594 F DEBUG   :       #57 pc 000dc5a1  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (art_quick_to_interpreter_bridge+32) (BuildId: a8203f4dd0e190bd1cbb4e57d1af3c8d)
05-25 23:17:07.786 25594 25594 F DEBUG   :       #58 pc 000d7bc5  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_stub_internal+68) (BuildId: a8203f4dd0e190bd1cbb4e57d1af3c8d)
05-25 23:17:07.786 25594 25594 F DEBUG   :       #59 pc 00440d6f  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_static_stub+246) (BuildId: a8203f4dd0e190bd1cbb4e57d1af3c8d)
05-25 23:17:07.787 25594 25594 F DEBUG   :       #60 pc 000dff77  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (art::ArtMethod::Invoke(art::Thread*, unsigned int*, unsigned int, art::JValue*, char const*)+186) (BuildId: a8203f4dd0e190bd1cbb4e57d1af3c8d)
05-25 23:17:07.787 25594 25594 F DEBUG   :       #61 pc 0037cb37  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (art::(anonymous namespace)::InvokeWithArgArray(art::ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnable const&, art::ArtMethod*, art::(anonymous namespace)::ArgArray*, art::JValue*, char const*)+54) (BuildId: a8203f4dd0e190bd1cbb4e57d1af3c8d)
05-25 23:17:07.787 25594 25594 F DEBUG   :       #62 pc 0037de01  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (art::InvokeMethod(art::ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnable const&, _jobject*, _jobject*, _jobject*, unsigned int)+788) (BuildId: a8203f4dd0e190bd1cbb4e57d1af3c8d)
05-25 23:17:07.787 25594 25594 F DEBUG   :       #63 pc 00329927  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (art::Method_invoke(_JNIEnv*, _jobject*, _jobject*, _jobjectArray*)+30) (BuildId: a8203f4dd0e190bd1cbb4e57d1af3c8d)
05-25 23:17:07.788 25594 25594 F DEBUG   :       #64 pc 000bb7e7  /system/framework/arm/boot.oat (art_jni_trampoline+110) (BuildId: 2aa4fd082df8c98f814fab6ceaa761ed35b0c737)
05-25 23:17:07.788 25594 25594 F DEBUG   :       #65 pc 000d7bc5  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_stub_internal+68) (BuildId: a8203f4dd0e190bd1cbb4e57d1af3c8d)
05-25 23:17:07.788 25594 25594 F DEBUG   :       #66 pc 00440c5b  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_stub+250) (BuildId: a8203f4dd0e190bd1cbb4e57d1af3c8d)
05-25 23:17:07.788 25594 25594 F DEBUG   :       #67 pc 000dff63  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (art::ArtMethod::Invoke(art::Thread*, unsigned int*, unsigned int, art::JValue*, char const*)+166) (BuildId: a8203f4dd0e190bd1cbb4e57d1af3c8d)
05-25 23:17:07.788 25594 25594 F DEBUG   :       #68 pc 00214917  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (art::interpreter::ArtInterpreterToCompiledCodeBridge(art::Thread*, art::ArtMethod*, art::ShadowFrame*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+270) (BuildId: a8203f4dd0e190bd1cbb4e57d1af3c8d)
05-25 23:17:07.789 25594 25594 F DEBUG   :       #69 pc 00210b31  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (bool art::interpreter::DoCall<false, false>(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::Instruction const*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+796) (BuildId: a8203f4dd0e190bd1cbb4e57d1af3c8d)
05-25 23:17:07.789 25594 25594 F DEBUG   :       #70 pc 00435f1f  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (MterpInvokeVirtual+594) (BuildId: a8203f4dd0e190bd1cbb4e57d1af3c8d)
05-25 23:17:07.789 25594 25594 F DEBUG   :       #71 pc 000d2814  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (mterp_op_invoke_virtual+20) (BuildId: a8203f4dd0e190bd1cbb4e57d1af3c8d)
05-25 23:17:07.790 25594 25594 F DEBUG   :       #72 pc 0034ce82  /system/framework/framework.jar (com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run+22)
05-25 23:17:07.790 25594 25594 F DEBUG   :       #73 pc 001f0d0b  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreterL7ExecuteEPNS_6ThreadERKNS_20CodeItemDataAccessorERNS_11ShadowFrameENS_6JValueEbb.llvm.17460432879466217+170) (BuildId: a8203f4dd0e190bd1cbb4e57d1af3c8d)
05-25 23:17:07.790 25594 25594 F DEBUG   :       #74 pc 001f56ed  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (art::interpreter::EnterInterpreterFromEntryPoint(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame*)+120) (BuildId: a8203f4dd0e190bd1cbb4e57d1af3c8d)
05-25 23:17:07.790 25594 25594 F DEBUG   :       #75 pc 0042a589  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (artQuickToInterpreterBridge+820) (BuildId: a8203f4dd0e190bd1cbb4e57d1af3c8d)
05-25 23:17:07.791 25594 25594 F DEBUG   :       #76 pc 000dc5a1  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (art_quick_to_interpreter_bridge+32) (BuildId: a8203f4dd0e190bd1cbb4e57d1af3c8d)
05-25 23:17:07.791 25594 25594 F DEBUG   :       #77 pc 00820bb5  /system/framework/arm/boot-framework.oat (com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main+2060) (BuildId: 57e39866938bab563b7c587c27534e03b4a54b2f)
05-25 23:17:07.791 25594 25594 F DEBUG   :       #78 pc 000d7bc5  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_stub_internal+68) (BuildId: a8203f4dd0e190bd1cbb4e57d1af3c8d)
05-25 23:17:07.791 25594 25594 F DEBUG   :       #79 pc 00440d6f  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_static_stub+246) (BuildId: a8203f4dd0e190bd1cbb4e57d1af3c8d)
05-25 23:17:07.791 25594 25594 F DEBUG   :       #80 pc 000dff77  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (art::ArtMethod::Invoke(art::Thread*, unsigned int*, unsigned int, art::JValue*, char const*)+186) (BuildId: a8203f4dd0e190bd1cbb4e57d1af3c8d)
05-25 23:17:07.791 25594 25594 F DEBUG   :       #81 pc 0037cb37  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (art::(anonymous namespace)::InvokeWithArgArray(art::ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnable const&, art::ArtMethod*, art::(anonymous namespace)::ArgArray*, art::JValue*, char const*)+54) (BuildId: a8203f4dd0e190bd1cbb4e57d1af3c8d)
05-25 23:17:07.792 25594 25594 F DEBUG   :       #82 pc 0037c969  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (art::InvokeWithVarArgs(art::ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnable const&, _jobject*, _jmethodID*, std::__va_list)+288) (BuildId: a8203f4dd0e190bd1cbb4e57d1af3c8d)
05-25 23:17:07.792 25594 25594 F DEBUG   :       #83 pc 002c4c1f  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (art::JNI::CallStaticVoidMethodV(_JNIEnv*, _jclass*, _jmethodID*, std::__va_list)+490) (BuildId: a8203f4dd0e190bd1cbb4e57d1af3c8d)
05-25 23:17:07.792 25594 25594 F DEBUG   :       #84 pc 0007d355  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (_JNIEnv::CallStaticVoidMethod(_jclass*, _jmethodID*, ...)+28) (BuildId: 14c98437e171a2edb14595cf0e1310f9)
05-25 23:17:07.793 25594 25594 F DEBUG   :       #85 pc 0007f747  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (android::AndroidRuntime::start(char const*, android::Vector<android::String8> const&, bool)+494) (BuildId: 14c98437e171a2edb14595cf0e1310f9)
05-25 23:17:07.793 25594 25594 F DEBUG   :       #86 pc 00002305  /system/bin/app_process32 (main+700) (BuildId: bc6fabfe213a46f8fca9b0bb216e5d21)
05-25 23:17:07.793 25594 25594 F DEBUG   :       #87 pc 00059267  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/bionic/libc.so (__libc_init+66) (BuildId: 382e04da0c4d6d7d06edbd53601a5dd4)
05-25 23:17:07.793 25594 25594 F DEBUG   :       #88 pc 00002033  /system/bin/app_process32 (_start_main+42) (BuildId: bc6fabfe213a46f8fca9b0bb216e5d21)
05-25 23:17:07.793 25594 25594 F DEBUG   :       #89 pc 00004456  <anonymous:e8ff3000>
```

Что делать?

Answer (score 1):

Данная ошибка вызвана проблемой на стороне железа, о чем свидетельствуют сл. строки лога:

```
Revision: '0'
```

версия ОТА:

> Build fingerprint: 'google/walley/walleye:10/QP1A.191105.004/eng.linux.20200228.134026:userdebug/test-keys'

```
QP1A.191105.004 - Google Pixel
```

Проблема должна решится обновлением OTA.
Обновил. Тестирую...

Comment: Не помогло. Так же вылетает. Тестировал на разных устройствах.
Может есть у кого мысли?